# List is not showing in Listview Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

i have implement a List from api and it gives me actual response which is working fine. but when i implemented a list search on it. Then the list doesn't show up when i open that screen. but when i start searching it gives me the correct search results.

here is my code:

```
  import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:fb_installer_phase1/api/controller/user_auth_controller.dart';
import 'package:fb_installer_phase1/api/model/technician.dart';
import 'package:fb_installer_phase1/views/user_management/add_user_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import '../../api/network_calls/api_configration.dart';
import '../../utils/app_constants.dart';
import '../../utils/color_resourse.dart';


class UserListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserListScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UserListScreen> createState() => _UserListScreenState();
}

class _UserListScreenState extends State<UserListScreen> {
  final TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  String keyword = '';


  bool isDataLoading = false;

  List<TechData> _technicians = <TechData>[];
  List<TechData> _techniciansList = <TechData>[];

  Future getData() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bearerToken = preferences.getString(AppConstants.appToken)!;

    String url = AppConstants.baseUrl + AppConstants.allTechnicianListApi;
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $bearerToken',
      });
      debugPrint("Token: $bearerToken");
      debugPrint("Response::: ${response.body}");
      TechnicianModel model = TechnicianModel.fromJson(
          jsonDecode(response.body));
      _technicians = model.data!;
      setState(() {
        isDataLoading = false;
        isDataLoading = !isDataLoading;
      });
      print("hello...: ${_technicians.length}");
    } catch (exception) {
      print(exception);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getAllTechniciansData();
    getData();
    
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: ColorResources.primaryColor,
        child: Center(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.add,
            size: 25.h,
          ),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Get.to(() => const AddUserScreen());
        },
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                end: Alignment.centerRight,
                stops: [
                  0.2,
                  0.7,
                  1,
                ],
                colors: [
                  Color(0XFF3DDA76),
                  Color(0XFF6DD2D1),
                  Color(0XFF41B1A1),
                ],
              )),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: ColorResources.primaryColor,
        title: const Text("User List"),
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 20.h,
          ),
          _createSearchbar(),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15.h,
          ),
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.w),
            height: 35.h,
            color: const Color(0xffF2F2F2),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 80.w,
                  height: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.w),
                  child: Text(
                    "Name",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontSize: 12.sp),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 170.w,
                  height: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.w),
                  child: Text(
                    "Email",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontSize: 12.sp),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.w),
                  child: Text(
                    "App Status",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontSize: 12.sp),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          _userListView(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
  }

  Container _createSearchbar() {
    return Container(
      height: 50.h,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.w),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          color: Colors.white,
          border: Border.all(color: ColorResources.grey300)),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 50.h,
            width: 40.h,
            child: const Center(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: ColorResources.primaryColor,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  contentPadding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.w, bottom: 11.h, top: 11, right: 15),
                  hintText: "Search here",
                ),
                onChanged: searchTechnicians,
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  Widget _userListView() {
    return isDataLoading || _techniciansList.isNotEmpty || controller.text.isNotEmpty

    ? Expanded(child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _techniciansList.length ,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (_techniciansList.isNotEmpty) {
            return Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.w),
              height: 32.h,
              //color: const Color(0xffF2F2F2),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 80.w,
                    height: double.infinity,
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.w),
                    child: Text(
                      _techniciansList[index].name!,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          fontSize: 11.sp),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 170.w,
                    height: double.infinity,
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.w),
                    child: Text(
                      _techniciansList[index].email!,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      maxLines: 2,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          fontSize: 11.sp),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      height: double.infinity,
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.w),
                      child: Text(
                        _techniciansList[index].phone! ?? '',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            fontSize: 11.sp),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return const SizedBox();
          }
        }
          ))
     : const Expanded(
      child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        color: ColorResources.primaryColor,)),
    );
  }



  searchTechnicians(String text) {
    _techniciansList.clear();
    if (text.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {

      });
      return;
    }
    _technicians.forEach((element) {
      if (element.name!.contains(text)
          || element.email!.contains(text)
          || element.phone!.contains(text)) {
        _techniciansList.add(element);
      }
    });
    print("searchresults: ${_techniciansList.length}");
    setState(() {

    });
   
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `!isDataLoading`? You want to show the list, when it is not loading anymore, right?

Comment: you want to show all _technicians when search field is empty? @AqeelMughal

Comment: yes @eamirho3ein

Answer (score 0):

Because initially your _techniciansList.length will be zero and your list view is depend on _techniciansList.length.

If you want to show the list you have to manage conditions like

if `controller.text.isEmpty` than show `ListView` with all product list

Answer (score 0):

You need check if search field is empty pass `_technicians`, like this:

```
Widget _userListView() {
    return isDataLoading ||
            _techniciansList.isNotEmpty ||
            controller.text.isNotEmpty ||
            _technicians.isNotEmpty
        ? Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: controller.text.isEmpty
                    ? _technicians.length
                    : _techniciansList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if (_techniciansList.isNotEmpty || _technicians.isNotEmpty) {
                    return Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.w),
                      height: 32.h,
                      //color: const Color(0xffF2F2F2),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: 80.w,
                            height: double.infinity,
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.w),
                            child: Text(
                              controller.text.isEmpty
                                  ? _technicians[index].name!
                                  : _techniciansList[index].name!,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  fontSize: 11.sp),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: 170.w,
                            height: double.infinity,
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.w),
                            child: Text(
                              controller.text.isEmpty
                                  ? _technicians[index].email!
                                  : _techniciansList[index].email!,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              maxLines: 2,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  fontSize: 11.sp),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                              height: double.infinity,
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.w),
                              child: Text(
                                controller.text.isEmpty
                                    ? _technicians[index].phone! ?? ''
                                    : _techniciansList[index].phone! ?? '',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    fontSize: 11.sp),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return const SizedBox();
                  }
                }))
        : const Expanded(
            child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: ColorResources.primaryColor,
            )),
          );
  }
```

Comment: @AqeelMughal was it what you want?